# 501 Error during Libjingle PCP on Amazon EC2 running Openfire

Tags: amazon-ec2, xmpp, openfire

I am trying to implement [Google's Libjingle (version: 0.6.14)](http://code.google.com/p/libjingle/) PCP example and I am getting a 501: feature not implemented error during execution. Specifically, the error occurs after each "account" has connected, been authenticated and began communicating with the other. An abbreviated log of the interaction is provided at the end.

I have set up my own jabber server (using OpenFire on an Amazon EC2 server), have opened all of the necessary ports and have added each "account" to the other's roster. The server has been set to allow for file transfers. My being new to working with servers, I am not sure why this error is occur and how to go about fixing it.

Thanks in advance,
AeroBuffalo

P.S. Let me know if there is any additional information needed (i.e. the full program log for either/both ends).

Receiving End:

```
[018:217] SEND >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> : Thu Jul  5 14:17:15 2012
[018:217]    <iq to="forgesend@forgejabber.com/pcp" type="set" id="5">
[018:217]      <jingle xmlns="urn:xmpp:jingle:1" action="session-initiate" sid="402024303" initiator="forgereceive@forgejabber.com/pcp">
[018:217]        <content name="securetunnel" creator="initiator">
[018:217]          <description xmlns="http://www.google.com/talk/securetunnel">
[018:217]            <type>send:winein.jpeg</type>
[018:217]            <client-cert>--BEGIN CERTIFICATE--END CERTIFICATE--</client-cert>
[018:217]          </description>
[018:217]          <transport xmlns="http://www.google.com/transport/p2p"/>
[018:217]        </content>
[018:217]      </jingle>
[018:217]      <session xmlns="http://www.google.com/session" type="initiate" id="402024303" initiator="forgereceive@forgejabber.com/pcp">
[018:217]        <description xmlns="http://www.google.com/talk/securetunnel">
[018:217]          <type>send:winein.jpeg</type>
[018:217]          <client-cert>--BEGIN CERTIFICATE--END CERTIFICATE--</client-cert>
[018:217]        </description></session>
[018:217]    </iq>
[018:217] RECV <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< : Thu Jul  5 14:17:15 2012
[018:217]    <presence to="forgereceive@forgejabber.com/pcp" from="forgesend" type="error">
[018:217]      <error code="404" type="cancel">
[018:217]        <remote-server-not-found xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/>
[018:217]      </error></presence>
[018:218] RECV <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< : Thu Jul  5 14:17:15 2012
[018:218]    <presence to="forgereceive@forgejabber.com/pcp" from="forgesend" type="error">
[018:218]      <error code="404" type="cancel">
[018:218]        <remote-server-not-found xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/>
[018:218]      </error></presence>
[018:264] RECV <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< : Thu Jul  5 14:17:15 2012
[018:264]    <iq type="result" id="3" to="forgereceive@forgejabber.com/pcp">
[018:264]      <query xmlns="google:jingleinfo">
[018:264]        <stun>
[018:264]          <server host="stun.xten.net" udp="3478"/>
[018:264]          <server host="jivesoftware.com" udp="3478"/>
[018:264]          <server host="igniterealtime.org" udp="3478"/>
[018:264]          <server host="stun.fwdnet.net" udp="3478"/>
[018:264]        </stun>
[018:264]        <publicip ip="65.101.207.121"/>
[018:264]      </query></iq>
[018:420] RECV <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< : Thu Jul  5 14:17:15 2012
[018:420]    <iq to="forgereceive@forgejabber.com/pcp" type="set" id="5" from="forgesend@forgejabber.com/pcp">
[018:420]      <jingle xmlns="urn:xmpp:jingle:1" action="session-initiate" sid="3548650675" initiator="forgesend@forgejabber.com/pcp">
[018:420]        <content name="securetunnel" creator="initiator">
[018:420]          <description xmlns="http://www.google.com/talk/securetunnel">
[018:420]            <type>recv:wineout.jpeg</type>
[018:420]            <client-cert>--BEGIN CERTIFICATE--END CERTIFICATE--</client-cert>
[018:420]          </description>
[018:420]          <transport xmlns="http://www.google.com/transport/p2p"/>
[018:420]        </content></jingle>
[018:420]      <session xmlns="http://www.google.com/session" type="initiate" id="3548650675" initiator="forgesend@forgejabber.com/pcp">
[018:420]        <description xmlns="http://www.google.com/talk/securetunnel">
[018:420]          <type>recv:wineout.jpeg</type>
[018:420]          <client-cert>--BEGIN CERTIFICATE--END CERTIFICATE--</client-cert>
[018:420]        </description></session></iq>
[018:421] TunnelSessionClientBase::OnSessionCreate: received=1
[018:421] Session:3548650675 Old state:STATE_INIT New state:STATE_RECEIVEDINITIATE Type:http://www.google.com/talk/securetunnel Transport:http://www.google.com/transport/p2p
[018:421] TunnelSession::OnSessionState(Session::STATE_RECEIVEDINITIATE)
[018:421] SEND >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> : Thu Jul  5 14:17:15 2012
[018:421]    <iq to="forgesend@forgejabber.com/pcp" id="5" type="result"/>
[018:465] RECV <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< : Thu Jul  5 14:17:15 2012
[018:465]    <iq to="forgereceive@forgejabber.com/pcp" id="5" type="result" from="forgesend@forgejabber.com/pcp"/>
[198:665] RECV <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< : Thu Jul  5 14:20:15 2012
[198:665]    <iq type="get" id="162-10" from="forgejabber.com" to="forgereceive@forgejabber.com/pcp">
[198:665]      <ping xmlns="urn:xmpp:ping"/>
[198:665]    /iq>
[198:665] SEND >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> : Thu Jul  5 14:20:15 2012
[198:665]    <iq type="error" id="162-10" to="forgejabber.com">
[198:665]      <ping xmlns="urn:xmpp:ping"/>
[198:665]      <error code="501" type="cancel">
[198:665]        <feature-not-implemented xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/>
[198:665]      </error>
[198:665]    </iq>
```

Sender:

```
[019:043] SEND >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> : Thu Jul  5 14:17:15 2012
[019:043]    <iq type="get" id="3">
[019:043]      <query xmlns="google:jingleinfo"/>
[019:043]    </iq>
[019:043] SEND >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> : Thu Jul  5 14:17:15 2012
[019:043]    <iq to="forgereceive@forgejabber.com/pcp" type="set" id="5">
[019:043]      <jingle xmlns="urn:xmpp:jingle:1" action="session-initiate" sid="3548650675" initiator="forgesend@forgejabber.com/pcp">
[019:043]        <content name="securetunnel" creator="initiator">
[019:043]          <description xmlns="http://www.google.com/talk/securetunnel">
[019:043]            <type>recv:wineout.jpeg</type>
[019:043]            <client-cert>--BEGIN CERTIFICATE----END CERTIFICATE--</client-cert>
[019:043]          </description>
[019:043]          <transport xmlns="http://www.google.com/transport/p2p"/>
[019:043]        </content>
[019:043]      </jingle>
[019:043]      <session xmlns="http://www.google.com/session" type="initiate" id="3548650675" initiator="forgesend@forgejabber.com/pcp">
[019:043]        <description xmlns="http://www.google.com/talk/securetunnel">
[019:043]          <type>recv:wineout.jpeg</type>
[019:043]          <client-cert>--BEGIN CERTIFICATE--END CERTIFICATE--</client-cert>
[019:043]        </description></session></iq>
[019:043] RECV <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< : Thu Jul  5 14:17:15 2012
[019:043]    <presence to="forgesend@forgejabber.com/pcp" from="forgereceive" type="error">
[019:043]      <error code="404" type="cancel">
[019:043]        <remote-server-not-found xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/>
[019:043]      </error></presence>
[019:044] RECV <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< : Thu Jul  5 14:17:15 2012
[019:044]    <presence to="forgesend@forgejabber.com/pcp" from="forgereceive" type="error">
[019:044]      <error code="404" type="cancel">
[019:044]        <remote-server-not-found xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/>
[019:044]      </error></presence>
[019:044] RECV <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< : Thu Jul  5 14:17:15 2012
[019:044]    <iq to="forgesend@forgejabber.com/pcp" type="set" id="5" from="forgereceive@forgejabber.com/pcp">
[019:044]      <jingle xmlns="urn:xmpp:jingle:1" action="session-initiate" sid="402024303" initiator="forgereceive@forgejabber.com/pcp">
[019:044]        <content name="securetunnel" creator="initiator">
[019:044]          <description xmlns="http://www.google.com/talk/securetunnel">
[019:044]            <type>send:winein.jpeg</type>
[019:044]            <client-cert>--BEGIN CERTIFICATE--END CERTIFICATE--</client-cert>
[019:044]          </description>
[019:044]          <transport xmlns="http://www.google.com/transport/p2p"/>
[019:044]        </content></jingle>
[019:044]      <session xmlns="http://www.google.com/session" type="initiate" id="402024303" initiator="forgereceive@forgejabber.com/pcp">
[019:044]        <description xmlns="http://www.google.com/talk/securetunnel">
[019:044]          <type>send:winein.jpeg</type>
[019:044]          <client-cert>--BEGIN CERTIFICATE--END CERTIFICATE--</client-cert>
[019:044]        </description></session></iq>
[019:044] TunnelSessionClientBase::OnSessionCreate: received=1
[019:044] Session:402024303 Old state:STATE_INIT New state:STATE_RECEIVEDINITIATE Type:http://www.google.com/talk/securetunnel Transport:http://www.google.com/transport/p2p
[019:044] TunnelSession::OnSessionState(Session::STATE_RECEIVEDINITIATE)
[019:044] SEND >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> : Thu Jul  5 14:17:15 2012
[019:044]    <iq to="forgereceive@forgejabber.com/pcp" id="5" type="result"/>
[019:088] RECV <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< : Thu Jul  5 14:17:15 2012
[019:088]    <iq type="result" id="3" to="forgesend@forgejabber.com/pcp">
[019:088]      <query xmlns="google:jingleinfo">
[019:088]        <stun>
[019:088]          <server host="stun.xten.net" udp="3478"/>
[019:088]          <server host="jivesoftware.com" udp="3478"/>
[019:088]          <server host="igniterealtime.org" udp="3478"/>
[019:088]          <server host="stun.fwdnet.net" udp="3478"/>
[019:088]        </stun>
[019:088]        <publicip ip="65.101.207.121"/>
[019:088]      </query>
[019:088]    </iq>
[019:183] RECV <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< : Thu Jul  5 14:17:15 2012
[019:183]    <iq to="forgesend@forgejabber.com/pcp" id="5" type="result" from="forgereceive@forgejabber.com/pcp"/>
[199:381] RECV <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< : Thu Jul  5 14:20:15 2012
[199:381]    <iq type="get" id="474-11" from="forgejabber.com" to="forgesend@forgejabber.com/pcp">
[199:381]      <ping xmlns="urn:xmpp:ping"/>
[199:381]    </iq>
[199:381] SEND >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> : Thu Jul  5 14:20:15 2012
[199:381]    <iq type="error" id="474-11" to="forgejabber.com">
[199:381]      <ping xmlns="urn:xmpp:ping"/>
[199:381]      <error code="501" type="cancel">
[199:381]        <feature-not-implemented xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/>
[199:382]      </error></iq>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this posting, I have crash coursed XMPP. This has made this error embarrassingly simple/obvious. For future people that might be experiencing this error, the reason for the error is because Libjingle has no implementation for the XMPP feature of pining, and thus has no idea how to handle a ping request from the XMPP/Jabber server. Since the two clients never setup the proper method of communicating a file transfer (an error on my execution of the code), the two just sat there waiting for something to happen, which made the server eventually ask if they were still there.